# Ruby on Rails decimals?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, decimal

I have a Migration in my database that has a `t.decimal` type called `decnum`. I have tried doing things like `mdl.decnum = 3.3`, and `mdl.save`, but it just saves `decnum` as `3`, instead of the decimal defined. Doing `mdl.decnum.class` returns `FixNum`, showing it is not a decimal type. I've also tried `mdl.decnum = BigDecimal.new("3.3")`, but that doesn't work as expected. Finally, I tried `mdl.decnum = 3.to_d`, but that didn't work either. How do I initialize my model, or set the variable after with a decimal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your migrationn should have something like this:

```
t.decimal :decnum, :precision => 9, :scale => 2, :default => '0.0'
```

Scale is number of charachers after the comma

Comment: Mine is currently formatted as `t.decimal :decnum, :precision => 15, :scale => 2`. Do I need the default variable for it to work correctly?

Comment: No, this is not necessary

Comment: Do you mean "is number of characters after the decimal" (.) ?